# Autocomplete typeahead search, using ajax calls troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use a text input as a search box, to retrieve search results via ajax calls, using bootstrap typeahead plugin

```
<form class="form-inline ml-3" action="/phone-autocomplete/">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input class="form-control form-control-navbar typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off"
         id="phone-autocomplete" type="search" name="searchstring" placeholder="search phone" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My data source returns a text/xml response like this:

```
[ "9876124", "9812124","9875124",]
```

My javascript, after including all required packages, is as follows:

```
    $('#phone-autocomplete').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('/phone-autocomplete/', { searchstring: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);
            });
            
        },
        'updater' : function(item) {
            this.$element[0].value = item;
            console.log(item);
            this.$element[0].form.submit();
            return item;
        }
    });
      
</script>
```

The purpose is for the search input to send a request every time the user types a character, and return back an updated list of items

The problem I have is it only works with one digit, then it stops being displayed for some reason

This is using the bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js package

Thanks

Comment: I think the cause might be the `form.submit();` in the updater? Why do you submit there? However, I did not reconstruct your code completely, so I can't be sure.

Comment: I was under the impression I need that submit to send the new keyword to the remote page, in order to get back an updated list of "found" items. I tried removing that line anyways, but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,
apparently, it's fundamental to set the MIME type of your remote response to    application/json, outputting a text string or HTML doesn't work and fails silently

Comment: Maybe add a `fail()` callback so that it doesn't fail silently?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your Ajax call because `typeahead` seems to be updating at each character typed in the search box, see demo:

```js
//
$('#phone-autocomplete').typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    data = ["9876124", "9812124", "9875124", ];
    console.log(`Ajax call with query: ${query}`);
    return process(data);
  },
  'updater': function(item) {
    this.$element[0].value = item;
    console.log(item);
    this.$element[0].form.submit();
    return item;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline ml-3" action="/phone-autocomplete/">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <input class="form-control form-control-navbar typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" id="phone-autocomplete" type="search" name="searchstring" placeholder="search phone" aria-label="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a demo showing how to get the output from the Ajax call (note: I set Ajax `async` to `false`).

See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```js
//
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false,
});
$('#phone-autocomplete').typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    console.log(`Ajax call with query: ${query}`);
    var data = [];
    $.get("example.php", function(data) {
        //alert("success");
      })
      .done(function() {
        //alert("second success");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        //alert("error");
      })
      .always(function() {
        //alert("finished");
        data = ["9876124", "9812124", "9875124", ];
        console.log(`data = ${data}`);
      });
    return process(data);
  },
  'updater': function(item) {
    this.$element[0].value = item;
    console.log(item);
    this.$element[0].form.submit();
    return item;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline ml-3" action="/phone-autocomplete/">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <input class="form-control form-control-navbar typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" id="phone-autocomplete" type="search" name="searchstring" placeholder="search phone" aria-label="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You just need to remove the lines

```
data = ["9876124", "9812124", "9875124", ];
console.log(`data = ${data}`);
```

from the `always` callback function and populate `data` in the `done` callback instead.
Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I go about populating data in the done callback? It's strange because when I visit manually my data provider URL it gives back the same array you hardcoded.. how would I "catch" the get request and assign it to data in the done callback?

Comment: Never mind, it was the MIME type, if it's not set to JSON it doesn't work! Thanks anyways!